# How to force focus a browser window using browser extension / plugin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am writing browser extensions for both chrome and firefox, and I am having a trouble finding how to focus a browser window that is currently out of focus but contains a tab that I want to focus.

Focusing a tab can be done when the browser window has focus.
However, the browser window does not come to focus when I focus a tab inside it.

To make it clearer,

I have two chrome browser windows open, each containing multiple tabs.
One of the window has a focus, and the other window contains a tab that I want to focus and show to the user.
Though I can focus the tab so that it comes on top of other tabs, the browser window does not come on top of other browser windows.

I wonder if such API is available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in Firefox you have [`BrowserWindow.activate()`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/windows.html#activate%28%29).

In Chrome you have [`chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true})`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-update)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it asap and give you a check!

Comment: sorry for the late comment, but is there a publicly available chrome plugin that allows me to somehow invoke chrome.windows.update?